# Java REST API for loop

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I developing app with java REST API and Spring Boot.
I'm having a problem.

```
JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("DailyForecasts");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {         
                    JSONObject jsonobject2=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    forecast.setTarih(jsonobject2.getString("Date"));
                    forecast.setGunDogumu(jsonobject2.getJSONObject("Sun").getString("Rise"));
                    forecast.setGunBatimi(jsonobject2.getJSONObject("Sun").getString("Set"));
                    forecast.setMinimumSicaklik(jsonobject2.getJSONObject("Temperature").getJSONObject("Minimum").getInt("Value"));
                    forecast.setMaksimumSicaklik(jsonobject2.getJSONObject("Temperature").getJSONObject("Maximum").getInt("Value"));


                    forecastList.add(forecast);
                }

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(path="/web/api/accu/tahmin/{city}")
    public List<ForecastData> CityWeatherForecast(@PathVariable("city") String city) {
        findLocation(HexString(city), APIKEY);
        weatherForecast(location.getKey(),APIKEY);

        return forecastList;
    }
```

I added the elements here to the list with the for loop.
But when I print, it only shows the last element.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the same object - forecast. You need to create the new object forcast every time in the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {         
    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();  // Line that you missed
    JSONObject jsonobject2=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    // your code goes here
    forecastList.add(forecast);
}
```

This should solve the problem.
The reason of this error is that same Forecast object got reassigned every loop and not new object. Creating the object as shown in above code should fix it.